# Clean way to integrate JS into JS

Tags: javascript, php

My goal is to generate some JS from PHP.
That is the content of my **script.php**

so I can use later

```
<script src="script.php?id=1&username=tom"></script>
```

here is the content of script.php

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["username"])) {
    $username=$_REQUEST["username"];
    $params.="&username=$username";
}
if (isset($_REQUEST["photo"])) {
    $photo=$_REQUEST["photo"];
    $params.="&photo=$photo";
}

?>
document.write('<link href="chat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"><\/script>');
document.write('<script src="chat.js.php<?=$params?>"></script>');
document.write('<div id="chatListUsers"></div>');
document.write('<div id="chatContainer"></div>');
```

Is there a way to make it cleaner than: 
document.write("....")

a kind of templating system ?

Comment: title is confusing

Comment: Why can't you just `echo` the paths to the scripts in your PHP?

Comment: @MirroredFate: How would that help here?!

Comment: Why are you adding this via a JS file?  Why not add this stuff in your main PHP/HTML file?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I was assuming he was trying to dynamically load templates, probably via `ajax`, in which case he could create a formatter to create a series of JS commands inserting the templates at the correct location, then run an eval on those commands.

Comment: Don't emit javascript through PHP.  Define a function in a static javscript file that can be called with the appropriate parameters in the HTML.

Comment: Also, passing ID and Username through the javascript and back to the server is concerning; it looks like there's no other security, which means anyone can change either of those values and pretend to be someone else.

Comment: @MirroredFate: But I don't see why JS is needed here at all!  I'd assume PHP already had `username` and `id` in the session.

Comment: Generated JS is usually a sign that you're coupling things that shouldn't be coupled, unless it's something like coffescript or typescript, which compile to JS.

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` is an alright way of dynamically adding a `script` tag to the page, but a better way would be to use a script loader [like these](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/essential-javascript-top-five-script-loaders-8122862).

But, it doesn't look like you want to add the `script` dynamically, it looks like you want to call the script with dynamic parameters, and in that case, you can just skip `document.write` altogether, and just use plain HTML, like so:

```
<script src="chat.js.php<?= $params ?>"></script>
```

Comment: That, plus the rest of the code that PHP is generating, like the divs and the CSS link tags, right? However, I think the OP wants to abstract it so you only need to add a single tag? For your answer to actually answer the question, you should show an example of using script loaders instead.